# likelihood ratio test statistic for the mean of two normal distributions with unequal variances

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I'm trying to derive the MLEs and likelihood ratio rest statistic for the following hypothesis test: that the two means are equal against a two sided alternative. I need the MLE for u, σ1^2 and σ2^2. I'm struggling to find the MLE for two normal distributions with unequal variances.

Let X1 . . . Xm be a random sample from a normal distribution with mean μ1 and variance σ1^2

Also, let Y1 . . . Yn be a random sample from a normal distribution with mean μ2 and variance σ2^2

Assume that the two samples are independent.

---

This is what I've got so far.
log likelihood: 
$−m/2 \log σ_1^2 − n/2 \log σ_2^2 − \frac12 σ_1^2∑_{i=1}^m(x_i−μ)^2
−\frac12 σ_2^2∑_{i=1}^n(y_i−μ)^2$

and from partial derivatives obtained the the following MLEs (which I think are correct):

$\hat μ=(∑_{i=1}^mx_i + ∑_{i=1}^ny_i)/ (m+n)$

$\hat{σ}_1^2=∑_{i=1}^m(x_i−\hat μ)^2/m$
$\hat{σ}_2^2=∑_{i=1}^n(y_i−\hat μ)^2/n$

Now stuck on the likelihood ratio test statistic based on the hypothesis test that $μ_1=μ_2=μ$.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "normal distribution with unequal variances."  Could you be more specific and accurate about the model for your data?

Comment: Sorry. I meant that the sample variances of the two normal distributions are not assumed to be equal. Assuming the null hypothesis is true (i.e. that u1=u2) then what are the MLE of u, σ1^2 and σ2^2

Comment: It is the population variances that are assumed to be unequal.

Comment: Okay, modulo the detail mentioned by @Michael, your problem is clearer.  Have you written down the log likelihood for this model?  That's where to begin.  Where exactly do you get stuck in deriving the MLE?

Comment: This is what I've got so far. 
log likelihood: 
−m/2 logσ1^2 − n/2 logσ2^2 − 1/2σ1^2∑m(xi−μ)^2
−1/2σ2^2∑n(yi−μ)2

and from partial derivatives obtained the the following MLEs (which I think are correct):

μ=(∑mxi + ∑nyi)/ m+n

σ1^2=∑m(xi−μ)^2/m
σ2^2=∑n(yi−μ)^2/n

Now stuck on the likelihood ratio test statistic based on the hypothesis test that μ1=μ2=μ.

Comment: I edited details into your post. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference#